# Package Cycle Metric with the File Design widget in SonarQube 5.4

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

We updated our SonarQube from 5.0 to 5.4, and now i want to add the "File Design" widget to our dashboard, but i cant find it under the widget list.

Was the widget removed from the standard widget list? I cant find any information about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *File Design*  widget is gone since SonarQube 5.2, together with other design-related services ([see SonarQube 5.2 Upgrade Notes](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE56/Release+5.2+Upgrade+Notes)).

Comment: so are there any similair plugins ?